# internalResourceViewResolver doesn't work in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jstl

I have the following simple application, and no matter where I put WEB-INF folder, I always get this error when I access http://localhost:8080:

> 2018-08-02 15:06:23.076  WARN 716 --- [nio-8100-exec-1]
>   o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP
>   request with URI [/WEB-INF/home.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'dispatcherServlet'

Here is all the code:

```
    package demo;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan
    @EnableWebMvc
    @Configuration
    public class DemoApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

.

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET;

import javax.management.RuntimeErrorException;

@Controller
@ComponentScan
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=GET)
    private String home() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

.

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("demo")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    // All web configuration will go here

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }
}
```

structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, all the code is actually find, for some reason I need to add this to maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```